# Unable to draw a circle in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, draw, geometry

i have a problem when i want to draw a circle in my map, but i dont find why. Please do somebody can tell me my problem, by the by i´m new using this platform and my english is not very well, so this is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
 <style type="text/css">  
    html { height: 100% }   
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }  
    #map_canvas { height: 100% } 
 </style> 
<script type="text/javascript"   
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
 </script> 


</script>
<script type= "text/javascript">

    var map;  
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.397, -100.644); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: #200444,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: #2E6444,
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        map: map,
        center: latlng,
        radius:20
    });
    function initialize() 
    {           
        var myOptions = {       
        zoom: 3,      
        center: latlng,       
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
       }     
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);  

    marker.setMap(map);
    } 


</script>
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()"> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:460px;"></div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. strokeColor and fillColor need to be strings:

   ```
   strokeColor: "#200444",
   fillColor: "#2E6444",
   ```
2. The radius of your circle is only 20 meters, you need to zoom in a little closer if you want to see it:

   ```
   zoom: 15,
   ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_drawCircle.html)